# test case for fread() errors in C

Tags: c, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, stdio

In one C application I'm maintaining,
there are a number of calls to `fread()`.

The return value is checked for the number of bytes read,
and stops when it reaches `0`,
meaning the file/stream end has been reached.

Now, that's not completely correct.
`fread()` may also return `0` if an error happens.
A way to check for that condition is to call `feof()` for example.

I can certainly add all these tests everywhere `fread()` is invoked. But that's not the point : it would be some kind of "blind fix". I need a test case to observe and repeat the problem, and observe the correction as part of CI tests.

So far, I have found none.
I have much less problems for `fwrite()`, where it's comparatively easier to create problems, but for `fread()`, I haven't found a reliable way to test issues *without also impacting* `fopen()`, which is a completely different situation already pretty well tested.

Any suggestion welcomed.

Comment: Read errors on ordinary files are pretty hard to cause, it usually takes a disk failure. You might have to link with a modified library that can trigger errors.

Comment: To be clear `feof()` reports if end-of-file is detected,  On `fread()` returning 0,  `feof()` is not necessarily a _not_ indication of "an error happened".  Use `ferror()` to detect "if an error happened".

Answer (score 1):

I see no robust standard solution.

C does not offer a clear method to simulate errors nor even set the `FILE*` *error indicator*.

Test code could, on a compiler/platform specific basis, set the `FILE`'s *error indicator*.  *Maybe* as simple as

```
#define SIM_ERROR(stream, ret) \
    while (1) {if (my_rand()==0) { (stream)_flags |= __SERR; (ret) = 0;} }

ret = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
SIM_ERROR(stream, ret);
```

Alternatively, a slightly more portable approach.   Code could, during test, could use its own functions as a temporary replacements to the standard library ones to cause an error.

```
int my_error_indicator = 0;
intptr_t my_stream = 0;

size_t my_fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream) {
  if (rand() == 0) {
    my_error_indicator = 1;
    my_stream = (intptr_t) stream;
    return 0; 
  }
  return fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}

int my_ferror(FILE *stream) {
  if (my_error_indicator && (intptr_t) stream == my_stream) {
    return my_error_indicator;
  }
  return ferror(stream);
}

void my_clearerr(FILE *stream) {
  if ((intptr_t) stream == my_stream) {
    my_stream = NULL;
    my_error_indicator = 0;
  }
  clearerr(stream);
}

#define fread my_fread
#define ferror my_ferror
#define clearerr my_clearerr
```

Replacements  `fclose(), rewind()` are needed too as they de-allocate and/or clear the error indicator.

Errors on multiple streams are not handled here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's typically the kind of complexity I'm trying to avoid, but well, sometimes ...

Comment: @Cyan Sometime, maybe too often, test code can exceed the size and complexity of code-under-test.  So what does that say about code to test the test code?  Hmmm?

Comment: Long test codes is not a concern. As you say, it happens, it's not rare.
I'm more concerned about "inserting in the middle", and basically inventing use cases I don't know about by pushing fake return values.
Not sure how valid / representative is such a test. Though it's certainly better than nothing.

It could just be a case I don't know enough how fread() / ferror() work to feel confident. Experience learns cautiousness.

Comment: you can set up a wrapper for the `fread()` function that is only used while testing.  That wrapper should reference some memory that it reads to determine if an error condition is to be returned or call the actual system function